# hydrogen environments of benzophenone

Tags: aromatic-compounds, nmr-spectroscopy

The hydrogen in $\ce{C4}$, $\ce{C6}$, $\ce{C10}$ and $\ce{C8}$ belong to same hydrogen environment.
The hydrogen in $\ce{C3}$, $\ce{C1}$, $\ce{C11}$ and $\ce{C13}$ belong to the another hydrogen environment.
Hydrogen in $\ce{C12}$ and $\ce{C2}$ belong to the once again, another hydrogen environment.

$\ce{C3}$, $\ce{C1}$ , $\ce{C11}$  $\ce{C13}$, $\ce{C12}$ and $\ce{C2}$ all have two hydrogen on the neighboring carbon atoms. 
So my question is why aren't they classified as one hydrogen environment? Instead, why are the categorized under two different environments?

[image: benzenephenone]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether environments are the same or not is based on **symmetry** considerations and **not** the number of hydrogens attached to the adjacent carbon atom.

Molecules and atoms within a molecule can be of three types:

- **identical** - they can be interconverted by simple rotations or translations.
- **enantiotopic** - they can be interconverted by reflection in a mirror or about a center of symmetry
- **diastereotopic** - they cannot be interconverted.

Molecules or atoms within a molecule that are found to be identical are said to be in the same environment.  Molecules or atoms that are identical, or in the same environment, **must** be identical with respect to **all** chemical and physical properties.  These properties would include chemical reactivity, spectroscopic environment, *etc.*

In benzophenone, I can rotate the benzene ring about the $\ce{C5-C7}$ bond. This rotation interconverts $\ce{C4}$ and $\ce{C6}$.  If I told you to look away and I performed this rotation (and we removed the numeric subscripts), there is no way that you could tell if the original carbon or the other carbon was now in the $\ce{C4}$ location.  These two carbons (and their attached hydrogens) are therefore said to be equivalent by the above definition.  The same applies to $\ce{C1}$ and $\ce{C3}$, they are also **equivalent to each other, or in the same environment.**

I can also rotate the molecule around the $\ce{C7=O}$ carbonyl axis.  If I do this I can interconvert $\ce{C4, C6, C8, C_{10}}$.  This same rotation also (separately) interconverts $\ce{C1, C3, C_{11}, C_{13}}$, and also (separately) $\ce{C2}$ and $\ce{C_{12}}$.

Therefore, these 3 sets of carbons

- $\ce{C4, C6, C8, C_{10}}$
- $\ce{C1, C3, C_{11}, C_{13}}$
- $\ce{C2, C_{12}}$

are different (diastereotopic) from one another (I can't interconvert $\ce{C4}$ and $\ce{C_{12}}$, for example).  So we have 3 different chemical environments, but **within each environment** there are several identical atoms. The same methodology and reasoning applies to the hydrogens attached to these carbons.  They also exist in 3 different environments, and within each of these 3 environments there are several equivalent hydrogens.